Long definite integral
I'm trying to compue the following integral on the interval $[0,\pi]$ on the $\theta$ variable.
(1/(4 Sqrt[2] r0^4 (Cos[\[Theta]]^6 + Sin[\[Theta]]^6)^(
 13/6)))(5 + 3 Cos[4 \[Theta]])^(
 1/6) (4 (Cos[\[Theta]]^6 + 
      Sin[\[Theta]]^6) (a15 r0^5 Cos[\[Theta]]^6 + 
      r0^4 Cos[\[Theta]]^5 ((a16 + b15) r0 Sin[\[Theta]] + 
         a10 (Cos[\[Theta]]^6 + Sin[\[Theta]]^6)^(1/6)) + 
      r0^3 Cos[\[Theta]]^4 ((a17 + b16) r0^2 Sin[\[Theta]]^2 + (a11 + 
            b10) r0 Sin[\[Theta]] (Cos[\[Theta]]^6 + 
            Sin[\[Theta]]^6)^(1/6) + 
         a6 (Cos[\[Theta]]^6 + Sin[\[Theta]]^6)^(1/3)) + 
      r0^2 Cos[\[Theta]]^3 ((a18 + b17) r0^3 Sin[\[Theta]]^3 + (a12 + 
            b11) r0^2 Sin[\[Theta]]^2 (Cos[\[Theta]]^6 + 
            Sin[\[Theta]]^6)^(
          1/6) + (a7 + b6) r0 Sin[\[Theta]] (Cos[\[Theta]]^6 + 
            Sin[\[Theta]]^6)^(1/3) + 
         a3 Sqrt[Cos[\[Theta]]^6 + Sin[\[Theta]]^6]) + 
      r0 Cos[\[Theta]]^2 ((a19 + b18) r0^4 Sin[\[Theta]]^4 + (a13 + 
            b12) r0^3 Sin[\[Theta]]^3 (Cos[\[Theta]]^6 + 
            Sin[\[Theta]]^6)^(
          1/6) + (a8 + b7) r0^2 Sin[\[Theta]]^2 (Cos[\[Theta]]^6 + 
            Sin[\[Theta]]^6)^(1/3) + (a4 + b3) r0 Sin[\[Theta]] Sqrt[
          Cos[\[Theta]]^6 + Sin[\[Theta]]^6] + 
         a1 (Cos[\[Theta]]^6 + Sin[\[Theta]]^6)^(2/3)) + 
      Cos[\[Theta]] ((a20 + b19) r0^5 Sin[\[Theta]]^5 + (a14 + 
            b13) r0^4 Sin[\[Theta]]^4 (Cos[\[Theta]]^6 + 
            Sin[\[Theta]]^6)^(
          1/6) + (a9 + b8) r0^3 Sin[\[Theta]]^3 (Cos[\[Theta]]^6 + 
            Sin[\[Theta]]^6)^(
          1/3) + (a5 + b4) r0^2 Sin[\[Theta]]^2 Sqrt[
          Cos[\[Theta]]^6 + 
           Sin[\[Theta]]^6] + (a2 + 
            b1) r0 Sin[\[Theta]] (Cos[\[Theta]]^6 + Sin[\[Theta]]^6)^(
          2/3) + a0 (Cos[\[Theta]]^6 + Sin[\[Theta]]^6)^(5/6)) + 
      Sin[\[Theta]] (b20 r0^5 Sin[\[Theta]]^5 + 
         b14 r0^4 Sin[\[Theta]]^4 (Cos[\[Theta]]^6 + 
            Sin[\[Theta]]^6)^(1/6) + 
         b9 r0^3 Sin[\[Theta]]^3 (Cos[\[Theta]]^6 + Sin[\[Theta]]^6)^(
          1/3) + b5 r0^2 Sin[\[Theta]]^2 Sqrt[
          Cos[\[Theta]]^6 + Sin[\[Theta]]^6] + 
         b2 r0 Sin[\[Theta]] (Cos[\[Theta]]^6 + Sin[\[Theta]]^6)^(
          2/3) + b0 (Cos[\[Theta]]^6 + Sin[\[Theta]]^6)^(
          5/6))) - (b15 r0^5 Cos[\[Theta]]^6 + 
      r0^4 Cos[\[Theta]]^5 ((-a15 + b16) r0 Sin[\[Theta]] + 
         b10 (Cos[\[Theta]]^6 + Sin[\[Theta]]^6)^(1/6)) + 
      r0^3 Cos[\[Theta]]^4 ((-a16 + 
            b17) r0^2 Sin[\[Theta]]^2 + (-a10 + 
            b11) r0 Sin[\[Theta]] (Cos[\[Theta]]^6 + 
            Sin[\[Theta]]^6)^(1/6) + 
         b6 (Cos[\[Theta]]^6 + Sin[\[Theta]]^6)^(1/3)) + 
      r0^2 Cos[\[Theta]]^3 ((-a17 + 
            b18) r0^3 Sin[\[Theta]]^3 + (-a11 + 
            b12) r0^2 Sin[\[Theta]]^2 (Cos[\[Theta]]^6 + 
            Sin[\[Theta]]^6)^(
          1/6) + (-a6 + b7) r0 Sin[\[Theta]] (Cos[\[Theta]]^6 + 
            Sin[\[Theta]]^6)^(1/3) + 
         b3 Sqrt[Cos[\[Theta]]^6 + Sin[\[Theta]]^6]) + 
      r0 Cos[\[Theta]]^2 ((-a18 + b19) r0^4 Sin[\[Theta]]^4 + (-a12 + 
            b13) r0^3 Sin[\[Theta]]^3 (Cos[\[Theta]]^6 + 
            Sin[\[Theta]]^6)^(
          1/6) + (-a7 + b8) r0^2 Sin[\[Theta]]^2 (Cos[\[Theta]]^6 + 
            Sin[\[Theta]]^6)^(1/3) + (-a3 + b4) r0 Sin[\[Theta]] Sqrt[
          Cos[\[Theta]]^6 + Sin[\[Theta]]^6] + 
         b1 (Cos[\[Theta]]^6 + Sin[\[Theta]]^6)^(2/3)) - 
      Sin[\[Theta]] (a20 r0^5 Sin[\[Theta]]^5 + 
         a14 r0^4 Sin[\[Theta]]^4 (Cos[\[Theta]]^6 + 
            Sin[\[Theta]]^6)^(1/6) + 
         a9 r0^3 Sin[\[Theta]]^3 (Cos[\[Theta]]^6 + Sin[\[Theta]]^6)^(
          1/3) + a5 r0^2 Sin[\[Theta]]^2 Sqrt[
          Cos[\[Theta]]^6 + Sin[\[Theta]]^6] + 
         a2 r0 Sin[\[Theta]] (Cos[\[Theta]]^6 + Sin[\[Theta]]^6)^(
          2/3) + a0 (Cos[\[Theta]]^6 + Sin[\[Theta]]^6)^(5/6)) + 
      Cos[\[Theta]] ((-a19 + b20) r0^5 Sin[\[Theta]]^5 + (-a13 + 
            b14) r0^4 Sin[\[Theta]]^4 (Cos[\[Theta]]^6 + 
            Sin[\[Theta]]^6)^(
          1/6) + (-a8 + b9) r0^3 Sin[\[Theta]]^3 (Cos[\[Theta]]^6 + 
            Sin[\[Theta]]^6)^(
          1/3) + (-a4 + b5) r0^2 Sin[\[Theta]]^2 Sqrt[
          Cos[\[Theta]]^6 + 
           Sin[\[Theta]]^6] + (-a1 + 
            b2) r0 Sin[\[Theta]] (Cos[\[Theta]]^6 + Sin[\[Theta]]^6)^(
          2/3) + b0 (Cos[\[Theta]]^6 + Sin[\[Theta]]^6)^(5/6))) Sin[
     4 \[Theta]])

But mathematica doesn't answer, I try to split the expresion, but also doesn't works. So could anyboydy give a hint to compute this integral?
I split the expresion on the following way
1/(4 Sqrt[2] r0^4 (Cos[\[Theta]]^6 + Sin[\[Theta]]^6)^(
  13/6)) (5 + 3 Cos[4 \[Theta]])^(
 1/6) (4 (Cos[\[Theta]]^6 + 
      Sin[\[Theta]]^6) (a15 r0^5 Cos[\[Theta]]^6 + 
      r0^4 Cos[\[Theta]]^5 ((a16 + b15) r0 Sin[\[Theta]] + 
         a10 (Cos[\[Theta]]^6 + Sin[\[Theta]]^6)^(1/6)) + 
      r0^3 Cos[\[Theta]]^4 ((a17 + b16) r0^2 Sin[\[Theta]]^2 + (a11 + 
            b10) r0 Sin[\[Theta]] (Cos[\[Theta]]^6 + 
            Sin[\[Theta]]^6)^(1/6) + 
         a6 (Cos[\[Theta]]^6 + Sin[\[Theta]]^6)^(1/3)) + 
      r0^2 Cos[\[Theta]]^3 ((a18 + b17) r0^3 Sin[\[Theta]]^3 + (a12 + 
            b11) r0^2 Sin[\[Theta]]^2 (Cos[\[Theta]]^6 + 
            Sin[\[Theta]]^6)^(
          1/6) + (a7 + b6) r0 Sin[\[Theta]] (Cos[\[Theta]]^6 + 
            Sin[\[Theta]]^6)^(1/3) + 
         a3 Sqrt[Cos[\[Theta]]^6 + Sin[\[Theta]]^6]) + 
      r0 Cos[\[Theta]]^2 ((a19 + b18) r0^4 Sin[\[Theta]]^4 + (a13 + 
            b12) r0^3 Sin[\[Theta]]^3 (Cos[\[Theta]]^6 + 
            Sin[\[Theta]]^6)^(
          1/6) + (a8 + b7) r0^2 Sin[\[Theta]]^2 (Cos[\[Theta]]^6 + 
            Sin[\[Theta]]^6)^(1/3) + (a4 + b3) r0 Sin[\[Theta]] Sqrt[
          Cos[\[Theta]]^6 + Sin[\[Theta]]^6] + 
         a1 (Cos[\[Theta]]^6 + Sin[\[Theta]]^6)^(2/3)) +
      
      
      
      Cos[\[Theta]] ((a20 + b19) r0^5 Sin[\[Theta]]^5 + (a14 + 
            b13) r0^4 Sin[\[Theta]]^4 (Cos[\[Theta]]^6 + 
            Sin[\[Theta]]^6)^(
          1/6) + (a9 + b8) r0^3 Sin[\[Theta]]^3 (Cos[\[Theta]]^6 + 
            Sin[\[Theta]]^6)^(
          1/3) + (a5 + b4) r0^2 Sin[\[Theta]]^2 Sqrt[
          Cos[\[Theta]]^6 + 
           Sin[\[Theta]]^6] + (a2 + 
            b1) r0 Sin[\[Theta]] (Cos[\[Theta]]^6 + Sin[\[Theta]]^6)^(
          2/3) + a0 (Cos[\[Theta]]^6 + Sin[\[Theta]]^6)^(5/6)) + 
      Sin[\[Theta]] (b20 r0^5 Sin[\[Theta]]^5 + 
         b14 r0^4 Sin[\[Theta]]^4 (Cos[\[Theta]]^6 + 
            Sin[\[Theta]]^6)^(1/6) + 
         b9 r0^3 Sin[\[Theta]]^3 (Cos[\[Theta]]^6 + Sin[\[Theta]]^6)^(
          1/3) + b5 r0^2 Sin[\[Theta]]^2 Sqrt[
          Cos[\[Theta]]^6 + Sin[\[Theta]]^6] + 
         b2 r0 Sin[\[Theta]] (Cos[\[Theta]]^6 + Sin[\[Theta]]^6)^(
          2/3) + b0 (Cos[\[Theta]]^6 + Sin[\[Theta]]^6)^(5/6))) -
   
   
   
   (b15 r0^5 Cos[\[Theta]]^6 + 
      r0^4 Cos[\[Theta]]^5 ((-a15 + b16) r0 Sin[\[Theta]] + 
         b10 (Cos[\[Theta]]^6 + Sin[\[Theta]]^6)^(1/6)) + 
      r0^3 Cos[\[Theta]]^4 ((-a16 + 
            b17) r0^2 Sin[\[Theta]]^2 + (-a10 + 
            b11) r0 Sin[\[Theta]] (Cos[\[Theta]]^6 + 
            Sin[\[Theta]]^6)^(1/6) + 
         b6 (Cos[\[Theta]]^6 + Sin[\[Theta]]^6)^(1/3)) + 
      r0^2 Cos[\[Theta]]^3 ((-a17 + 
            b18) r0^3 Sin[\[Theta]]^3 + (-a11 + 
            b12) r0^2 Sin[\[Theta]]^2 (Cos[\[Theta]]^6 + 
            Sin[\[Theta]]^6)^(
          1/6) + (-a6 + b7) r0 Sin[\[Theta]] (Cos[\[Theta]]^6 + 
            Sin[\[Theta]]^6)^(1/3) + 
         b3 Sqrt[Cos[\[Theta]]^6 + Sin[\[Theta]]^6]) + 
      r0 Cos[\[Theta]]^2 ((-a18 + b19) r0^4 Sin[\[Theta]]^4 + (-a12 + 
            b13) r0^3 Sin[\[Theta]]^3 (Cos[\[Theta]]^6 + 
            Sin[\[Theta]]^6)^(
          1/6) + (-a7 + b8) r0^2 Sin[\[Theta]]^2 (Cos[\[Theta]]^6 + 
            Sin[\[Theta]]^6)^(1/3) + (-a3 + b4) r0 Sin[\[Theta]] Sqrt[
          Cos[\[Theta]]^6 + Sin[\[Theta]]^6] + 
         b1 (Cos[\[Theta]]^6 + Sin[\[Theta]]^6)^(2/3)) - 
      Sin[\[Theta]] (a20 r0^5 Sin[\[Theta]]^5 + 
         a14 r0^4 Sin[\[Theta]]^4 (Cos[\[Theta]]^6 + 
            Sin[\[Theta]]^6)^(1/6) + 
         a9 r0^3 Sin[\[Theta]]^3 (Cos[\[Theta]]^6 + Sin[\[Theta]]^6)^(
          1/3) + a5 r0^2 Sin[\[Theta]]^2 Sqrt[
          Cos[\[Theta]]^6 + Sin[\[Theta]]^6] + 
         a2 r0 Sin[\[Theta]] (Cos[\[Theta]]^6 + Sin[\[Theta]]^6)^(
          2/3) + a0 (Cos[\[Theta]]^6 + Sin[\[Theta]]^6)^(5/6)) + 
      Cos[\[Theta]] ((-a19 + b20) r0^5 Sin[\[Theta]]^5 + (-a13 + 
            b14) r0^4 Sin[\[Theta]]^4 (Cos[\[Theta]]^6 + 
            Sin[\[Theta]]^6)^(
          1/6) + (-a8 + b9) r0^3 Sin[\[Theta]]^3 (Cos[\[Theta]]^6 + 
            Sin[\[Theta]]^6)^(
          1/3) + (-a4 + b5) r0^2 Sin[\[Theta]]^2 Sqrt[
          Cos[\[Theta]]^6 + 
           Sin[\[Theta]]^6] + (-a1 + 
            b2) r0 Sin[\[Theta]] (Cos[\[Theta]]^6 + Sin[\[Theta]]^6)^(
          2/3) + b0 (Cos[\[Theta]]^6 + Sin[\[Theta]]^6)^(5/6))) Sin[
     4 \[Theta]])

And compute each integral, but doesn't work. for instance in the second block the answer that mathematica give me is in gray and not in black Why? I don't know.

Here is a partial, maybe even a complete, solution.
v=Expand[...your huge expression...]

That turns your huge expression into the sum of 126 p/q smaller simpler expressions.
Then
Map[Integrate[#,{\[Theta],0,Pi}]&,Take[v,20]]

will happily fairly quickly integrate the sum of the first 20 p/q expressions and
Map[Integrate[#,{\[Theta],0,Pi}]&,Take[v,-6]]

will try to integrate the sum of the last six p/q expressions.
You can look at the 49th p/q expression using
v[[49]]

or look at the sum of the first 20 p/q expressions using
Take[v,20]

Some of those p/q are far easier and faster to integrate than others.
But maybe, if you wait long enough, and you are very very lucky then
Map[Integrate[#,{\[Theta],0,Pi}]&,v]

will give you the the integral of your entire expression, but at least you can see some progress on this if you integrate subsets of your complete expression.
I am guessing that the reason your attempt at splitting your integrand into three parts didn't work is that the ( before the 4 near the top of your third line that begins with 1/6) (4..., that ( only matches the final ) which is at the end of the last line in your third part. Does this make any sense?
Good luck. And test this very carefully to try to make sure I haven't made any mistakes.

Integrate[Take[v,24],{\[Theta],0,Pi}] finishes fairly quickly. Changing 24 to 25 times out for me. If you look at v[[25]] and imagine trying to do that by hand then you might understand. If I try Integrate[FullSimplify[v[[25]]],{\[Theta],0,Pi}] then it takes a while for the FullSimplify to finish and a while longer for the Integrate to finish, but the result for that turns out to be zero. FullSimplify is far too slow to use on your entire expression, but trying that for some of the harder integrals might get you the solution you are looking for. I hope it works for you.

And v[[26]] is even harder than v[[25]] but the same trick is barely enough. Maybe some of the following integrals will be easier or maybe they will be even harder. Good luck

Hi Bill, thanks for your answer was very usefull. In the expresioin 25 my computer don't do this integral. v25= (a11 Cos[[Theta]]^10 (5 + 3 Cos[4 [Theta]])^(1/6)
Sin[[Theta]])/(Sqrt[2] (Cos[[Theta]]^6 + Sin[[Theta]]^6)^2). Only acts like mathematica already solved it. Could give some reason?

When MMA returns the original, or a slightly modified version of the original, instead of the hopefully small simple answer you really want then that is MMA`s way of saying "I have no idea how to do this so the answer is just giving you back the question that you asked." Your problem has lots of fractional powers and those usually make very difficult problems. And there might be some zero denominators lurking in there too, which also makes problems much harder. Is there any way the original problem could be somehow simplified in any way?

Hi Bill thanks. I understand. Regard to the simplify the problem I don't belive that it is possible, but with your hint I get advance.
